# Using a single dropwizard MetricRegistry for the dropwizard application as well as BigtableClientMetrics

Tags: dropwizard, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a Dropwizard application that uses Dropwizard metrics and uses BigTable for persistence. I am already reporting metrics to graphite from my application and would like to report client side BigTable metrics too. I see that there is an existing class `BigtableClientMetrics` that supports reporting client-side metrics. `DropwizardMetricRegistry` is also provided which wraps the dropwizard `MetricRegistry` and creates an instance of the class. Considering an instance of the `MetricRegistry` is already created as part of bootstrap of my application, is there any way I can use the same instance for reporting Bigtable client metrics too?

Would be great if the `DropwizardMetricRegistry` class would have a constructor that takes a dropwizard `MetricRegistry` object as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a Cloud Bigtable HBase client feature request.  Please submit an issue here: https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-bigtable-client

Comment: Created an issue, https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/2133 Thanks @Solomon